# How to install spring boot CLI on Mac?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to install the Spring Boot CLI. I followed the instructions from the website. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html) The error I am getting is:

$ spring --version
rbenv: spring: command not found

The `spring' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.0

I ran all the brew and bundle installs, but I am still running into issues. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 23):

Better using **Homebrew**

1. Install Homebrew using `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Check if Homebrew installed using `brew -v`
3. Update Homebrew packager `brew tap spring-io/tap`
4. Install Spring Boot CLI using `brew install spring-boot`

> Homebrew installs spring to /usr/local/bin

5. Check Spring Boot CLI using `spring version`

---

If you want to remove it use `brew uninstall spring-boot`, add additional `--force` to force it

---

Update: Repository for Spring Boot has been moved from `pivotal/tap` to `spring-io/tap`

See the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html)

Comment: The official docs should be updated to reflect the need for the pivotal/tap so this answer was quite helpful.

Comment: This answer was correct but an answer further down is current. Look for the Spring Boot has relocated to spring-io/tap

Answer (score 11):

Spring Boot has relocated to spring-io/tap

```
brew tap spring-io/tap
brew uninstall springboot
brew install spring-boot
```

Answer (score 5):

Windows users:

Download the zip

```
https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-cli/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-cli-2.0.2.RELEASE-bin.zip
```

Extract & Run spring.bat inside the /bin folder

Mac users:

```
$> brew tap pivotal/tap

$> brew install springboot
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use sdkman http://sdkman.io/ I cannot submit such a short answer so added more text...