# Ruby on rails on mac - Could not find generator 'devise:install'. and zsh: command not found: spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos-monterey

Hi I'm having two error codes: Could not find generator 'devise:install'. and zsh: command not found: spring

So I typed gem install bundler and bundle install. Then I closed my terminal and opened it again, but it is still not working.

Comment: I had an error with spring bc it's not installed. If you're having the same issue, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704002/how-to-install-spring-boot-cli-on-mac

Comment: but still i'm having an issue when i type: spring stop ( 'stop' is not a valid command. See 'help'.)

Comment: What did you do that caused these errors

Answer (score 1):

You on Rails7?  `spring` isn't included anymore.